# Writing Kernel on Matlab for GPU parallelized Value Function Iteration

Tags: matlab, julia, gpu

I'd like to write a matlab function that does Value Function Iteration on GPU. 
What I have in mind is very similar to this code written in Julia:
[Value Function Iteration under uncertainty](https://github.com/giob1994/GPU-OpenCL-VFI-in-Julia/blob/master/GPU%20Value%20Function%20Iteration%20under%20Uncertainty.ipynb)

I'm really struggling in writing the kernel for the GPU. 
In the Julia-Code, doing so looks like this:

`# Write kernel for GPU manually:`
`gpu_call(grid, (grid, V, policy, z, P, Float32(alpha), Float32(beta), Float32(delta), Float32(sigma), UInt32(SIZE_GRID), UInt32(SIZE_Z)))`
`do state, grid, V, policy, z, P, alpha, beta, delta, sigma, SIZE_GRID, SIZE_Z`
`# Each kernel executes for one value of the capital grid:`
`idx = @linearidx grid`

What would be the equivalent functions in matlab for 
`gpu_call( )` and `__ = @linearidx __`?

The only thing similair to gpu_call that I found was:
`KERN = parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel(PTXFILE,CPROTO)`
But this requires code based on C for CUDA or OpenCL, if I understand it correctly. I am unable to deal with such code.

I have the parallel computing toolkit installed.

Thanks for any help, tips or advice! :)

EDIT: 
My very rough sketch of the function (without the part I don't get) looks like this:

```
function [V,pol] = VFI_own_gpu_attempt(alpha,beta,delta,eta,z_grid,k_grid,pi_z,tol)
size_k_grid = size(k_grid,1);
size_z_grid = length(z_grid);

k_grid_G = gpuArray(k_grid);
z_grid_G = gpuArray(z_grid);
pi_z_G = gpuArray(pi_z);
V0 = ones(size_k_grid,size_z_grid,'gpuArrays');
V = ones(size_k_grid,size_z_grid,'gpuArrays');
pol = zeros(size_k_grid,size_z_grid,'gpuArrays');

while abs(V-V0)>tol
V0 = V;
% write kernel
%gpu_call(...)

% each kernel executes for one value of the capital grid
%idx = @linearidx grid

for i_z = 1:size_z_grid
F = -Inf;
pol_i = uint(1)
    for i_k = 1_size_k_grid
    c = z_grid_G(i_z)*k_grid_G(idx)^alpha + (1-delta)*k_grid_G(idx) - k_grid_G(i_k)M
        if c>0
        F0 = ((c)^(1-eta)-1)/(1-eta)
            for j = 1:size_z_grid
                F1 = F0 + beta*pi_z_G(i_z,j)*V(i_k,j);
            end
        end
        if F1 > F
        F = F1;
        pol_i = uint64(i_k);
        end
    end
V(idx,i_z) = F;
pol(idx,i_z) = pol_i;

end
```

EDIT 2:
I tried a different approach with **arrayfun**. 
The main.m is:

```
alpha=0.35;
beta= 0.984;
delta=0.01;
eta=2;

tol=10^(-4);

% Not using Tauchen but some transition matrix with 3 grid points for stochastic process
z_grid = [0.4,0.8,1.2];
pi_z = [0.7,0.2,0.1;0.1,0.8,0.1;0.05,0.1,0.85];

% capital grid
k_min = 0.01;
k_max = 20;
n_k = 1000;
k_grid = linspace(k_min,k_max,n_k);

% prepare objects for GPU
k = gpuArray(k_grid);
z = gpuArray(z_grid);
pi_z_G = gpuArray(pi_z);

size_k = size(k,2);
size_z = length(z);

V0 = zeros(size_k,size_z,'gpuArray');
V = ones(size_k,size_z,'gpuArray');
pol = zeros(size_k,size_z,'gpuArray');
diff=max(max(V-V0));

while abs(diff)>tol
V0 = V;
y_k = (k.^alpha)'*z+ (1-delta)*k(ones(1,size_z),:)';

for i_k = 1:size_k
    for i_z = 1:size_z

[V,pol]= arrayfun(@VFI_own_gpu_attempt1,V0,y_k,i_k,i_z, alpha, beta, delta, eta,size_k, size_z,z,k,pi_z_G);
    end
end
diff=max(max(V-V0));
end
toc
```

And the VFI-function is:

```
function [V,pol] = VFI_own_gpu_attempt1(V0,y_k,i_k,i_z,alpha, beta, delta, eta,size_k,size_z,z,k,pi_z_G)
    low_k=1;
    if(y_k(i_k,i_z) > k(end))
        high_k = length(k);
    else
        high_k= find(k > y_k(i_k,i_z), 1);
    end

    if(k(high_k) > y_k(i_k,i_z))
    high_k = high_k -1;
    end

    N_k = high_k; 
%maximization 
F = ((y_k(i_k,i_z)*ones(N_k,1) - k(low_k:high_k)').^(1-eta))/(1-eta) + beta*V0(low_k:high_k,:)*pi_z_G(i_z,:)';
[V(i_k,i_z),pol(i_k,i_z)]=max(F);


end
```

The code stops when trying to run the line with the **arrayfun**. 
The error message says:

```
Error using gpuArray/arrayfun
```

Matrix dimensions must agree.

```
Error in own_gpu_attempt (line 41)
[V,pol]= arrayfun(@VFI_own_gpu_attempt1,V0,y_k,i_k,i_z, alpha, beta, delta, eta,size_k,
size_z,z,k,pi_z_G);
```

However, when I turn line 41 from an arrayfun to just a normal CPU function, the function executes fine. How could this be?

Comment: It's probably easier to just port the remainder of the code to Julia rather than the GPU bit to Matlab...

Comment: Probably true for this problem. But I'm not familiar with Julia and would want to write future code on matlab aswell :) But thanks for the advice!

Comment: You can try to call Julia from MATLAB for your computational intensive tasks only: see https://github.com/Timmmdavis/MATLABToJuliaViaPythonAndBackAgain... and https://github.com/juliamatlab/mexjulia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `arrayfun()` on GPU requires inputs to either be the grid (or a specific dimension of it) or to be scalar. While on the CPU it will accept matrices and the like (e.g., your pi_z_G) as inputs.

You can find a generic implementation that works on the GPU in the vfitoolkit.com (a Matlab package). It is inside the `ValueFnIter_Case1()` command.

Whether you just use this or use it to understand when and how to use `arrayfun()` on GPU, is up to you.

Essentially is a matter of just being more specific about which parts of your code are actually functions to be evaluated on the grid, and which are not.

[Edit:I dev vfitoolkit, but my point here was just about how arrayfun() works in matlab; have added this as was not my intention to spam.]